# How can I filter the records of an array in Angular?

Tags: angular, frontend

I have a data-source which is an array having 43 elements in it. Now I want to filter the records based on the assignedTo field which is there in the data source array. I want create filtered_data only for users in assignedTo(User1,User2,User3,User4).
I tried using array.filter but nothing good came up. i am new in angular and hence this question might seem easy to few. Any help is much much appriciated.
Regards

```
this.TabsService.groupExceptionReports(BaseUrl, headers, numcalls).then(
      (data) => {
        this.dataSource = <issues>data;
        console.log(this.dataSource);
      }

    );
```

```
{
number: 0
id: "MAM-107"
summ: "0 - Systems Exceptions"
assignedTo: "Reporting User"
syno: "<p><b><ins>Sunday, April 19</ins> <font color="#0000ff">&lt;No New Updates&gt;
ragColour: "<div style="background-color:orange;width:50px;height:25px;border-radius:5px">&nbsp;</div>"
synoDate: "April 19, 2020, 07:57:47"
}
```

Comment: can you provide sample array of data?

Comment: number: 0
id: "MAM-107"
summ: "0 - Systems Exceptions"
assignedTo: "Reporting User"
syno: "<p><b><ins>Sunday, April 19</ins> <font color="#0000ff">&lt;No New Updates&gt;</font></b></p>↵<ul>↵ <li>General : ergonomics while WFH
ragColour: "<div style="background-color:orange;width:50px;height:25px;border-radius:5px">&nbsp;</div>"
synoDate: "April 19, 2020, 07:57:47"

Comment: please take the latest edited. Thanks

Comment: i want you json array of data, and can you format and explain about your provided data.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda. I have added the sample data in the question itself. So its bascially the extracted data out of a rest api and then I am displaying it in a mat-table. Basically I want to filter the data based on the 'assignedTo' key. I only want data for which the assignedTo is in (Reporting User 1 , Reporting User 2, Reporting User 3)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mcvsik?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts checkout this link is it what you are trying to do?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Not really. So what i want is let's say there are 40 such arrays and in the datasource. I only want to pick array for the users 1,2,3,4 based on the assignedTo field. So, m final output in the table would have 4 records instead of 40 now.

Comment: checkout my updated link here in this...  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mcvsik?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212094/discussion-between-jayashri-and-gaurangdhorda).